# Como bloquear <footer> al chocar con <main> para que no se sitúe uno encima del otro y haga scroll el main?

Tags: html, css, css3, scroll

Me explico tengo 2 cajas 1 caja para el main y otra para el footer, cuando hago scroll sobre la pagina una caja pasa por encima de otra ya que tengo esto para que el footer se quede pegado abajo del todo:

```
position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
```

de forma que si hago pequeña la ventana desde abajo footer siempre pasa por encima del main. No se si logro explicarme. La idea es que cuando el footer que esta pegado abajo del todo choque contra la caja del main se quede parado sin avanzar y salga un scroll en el main para que este pueda seguir bajando sin interferir en mi footer.

Añado las propiedades de ambos para ver si me podéis ayudar, también añado un borde para que veais cada caja:

```css
main {
    margin-top: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
    background-color: #5fb5ce;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
<p>texto</p>
</main>
<footer>
<p>texto</p>
</footer>
```

Muchas gracias!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes en el `<main>` posicionarlo como `fixed` para que las coordenadas sean relativas a la ventana. Darle el porcentaje que quieras que ocupe con el `height` y al otro contenedor (footer) que también esta posicionado darle el resto del porcentaje. Y utilizar la propiedad `overflow-y` para el scroll del contenido. Le coloqué algunos Lorems para que se vea el efecto.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 88%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
footer {
    background-color: #5fb5ce;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 11%;
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
        necessitatibus iste earum possimus consequatur beatae aliquid aspernatur
        optio, rerum reprehenderit velit veritatis quibusdam! Repudiandae
        molestiae veniam quaerat quisquam, quae in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iste
        est voluptate esse quis iure! Rem eos, saepe totam perferendis, esse
        laborum similique eum quisquam nobis quod ducimus itaque!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure tenetur
        illo quasi, aut quia reprehenderit aliquid, distinctio et aspernatur
        veniam modi autem. Magni laudantium quod quaerat est sint ipsam aliquam.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum commodi
        alias laborum, excepturi sint, eius provident, tempora neque nihil sed
        molestias eligendi nulla dignissimos eos distinctio. Obcaecati
        consectetur eius a.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quia
        explicabo similique exercitationem eveniet dolores sequi nulla, cumque
        iure vero quam molestias facilis nobis omnis error modi sunt facere
        voluptates?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui omnis
        amet, earum animi ea tempore excepturi? Soluta vero placeat neque ipsam
        repudiandae aliquid molestias excepturi, voluptas iure illum quia
        deserunt.
      </p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>texto</p>
    </footer>
```

Ejecutalo y dale en pantalla completa para ver mejor. Espero te guíe.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! justo neceitaba eso :)

Comment: Bueno, de nada.